# How do I get the raw content of attachment resources from Java SDK in MS Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to use the Java SDK of MS Graph to look up raw content (/$value endpoint) of the attachment.

For /messages resources, I know that raw content can be inquired in the following way.

```java
@Test
void downloadEmlFile() {
    // while empty value, but let's assume there is a value.
    String userId = ""; 
    String messageId = "";

    InputStream inputStream = 
        graphServiceClient.users(userId).messages(messageId)
            .content()
            .buildRequest()
            .get();
}
```

As you can see above, MS Graph SDK provides an api called *.content()* for messages.

However, it seems that they do not provide the corresponding api for the attachment resource.

In summary, there are two things I am curious about

1. Why don't you provide an API like *.content()* for the attachment resource?
2. How do I get raw content (/$value) for an attachment?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use the `FileAttachmentRequestBuilder` which has the `content` method.

```
@Test
void downloadEmlFile() {
    // while empty value, but let's assume there is a value.
    String userId = ""; 
    String messageId = "";
    String attachmentId = "";

    String requestUrl = graphServiceClient.users(userId).messages(messageId)
            .attachments(attachmentId)
            .getRequestUrl();

    FileAttachmentRequestBuilder fileAttachReqBuilder = new FileAttachmentRequestBuilder(
             requestUrl, 
             graphServiceClient, 
             null)

    InputStream inputStream = fileAttachReqBuilder
                                 .content()
                                 .buildRequest()
                                 .get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FileAttachment class.

```
FileAttachment attachment = (FileAttachment) message.attachments.getCurrentPage().get(0);
attachment.contentBytes
```